# Uvicorm - Fastapi - "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop" when deploying app to docker

Tags: docker, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm trying to run my app in docker using `docker build -t` and I keep getting this stack trace error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 454, in main
h11_max_incomplete_event_size=h11_max_incomplete_event_size,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 576, in run
server.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
return loop.run_until_complete(main)
File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1501, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
config.load()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 485, in load
self.loaded_app = self.loaded_app()
File "./projectname/main.py", line 45, in main
factory=True,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 576, in run
server.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 34, in run
"asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

I never get it when I run my code on my machine normally:

```
uvicorn my_project.main:main --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-5000}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.9

WORKDIR /

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r ./requirements.txt

CMD ["uvicorn", "project_module.main:main", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

I have also tried deploying to heroku but got same results.
Any idea what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What does your code look like? Especially the main.py file.

Comment: Issue is fixed. Adding code anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by having this as app.py:

```
from pathlib import Path

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import UJSONResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from main_module.web.api.router import api_router

APP_ROOT = Path(__file__).parent.parent

def get_app() -> FastAPI:
    app = FastAPI(
        title="main_module",
        description="",
        docs_url=None,
        redoc_url=None,
        openapi_url="/api/openapi.json",
        default_response_class=UJSONResponse,
    )

    app.include_router(router=api_router, prefix="/api")
    app.mount('/', StaticFiles(directory='dist', html=True))

    origins = ["*"]
    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=origins,
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )

    return app
```